# Como instalar Maven en windows

Tags: java, maven

Siguiendo este tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm

Descargue maven desde 
http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Estoy agregando estas variables:  en el path del sistema.

```
M2_HOME:
C:\programs\apache-maven-3.0.3

M2:
%M2_HOME%\bin

JAVA_HOME:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25

Path:
%JAVA_HOME%\bin; %M2%
```

No reconoce el comando `mvn`

**edit: 1**

El directorio `bin` contiene: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

edit: 2

para la creacion de las variables para maven, cree variable con sus valores, de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

segui  los pasos de @Voiser

> reinicie la maquina, ahora sale este error Could not find or load main
>   class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

***edit 3:***
las variables en mi sistema son:

> C:\Users\DH-User15>echo %M2_HOME% %M2_HOME%
>
> C:\Users\DH-User15>echo %M3_HOME% C:\apache-maven-3.5.0
>
> C:\Users\DH-User15>echo %M2% C:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin
>
> C:\Users\DH-User15>echo %path% ...
>   C:\apache-maven-3.5.0\apache-maven\src\bin

Comment: Ya reiniciaste la pc?, me ha pasado que toma los cambios al reiniciar, si  sigue igual intenta poniendo los valores en path directo : C:\programs\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin

Agrego: asegurate de que en esa ruta esten los binarios de maven.

Comment: @Voiser no es necesario insertar esas 3 variables que postee en mi pregunta? seria solamente poner C:\programs\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin ?

Comment: Para maven, basta con crear M2 y M2_HOME, el pre requisito es previamente contar con la variable de java Home, y editar la variable Path para gregar la ruta donde estan los binarios de Maven ./bin/

Comment: Duda,  en tu variable Path, que valor tiene para maven?

Comment: Oye ya veo, te bajaste la version de src , debes bajar los binarios, la version que se ve en tu Path, es el codigo fuente. Baja el ZIP: 
Binary zip archive apache-maven-3.5.0-bin.zip  ya que por lo que veo tienes la version: Source zip archive apache-maven-3.5.0-src.zip

Comment: @Voiser sabes como compilar con maven un proyecto de spring-boot en el ide intellij-idea ?

Comment: No he utilizado ese ide, pero imagino que debe tener un plugin  para conectar maven con el proyecto o en su defecto, compilar desde cmd posicionandote en la ruta del proyecto  para usar un mvn clean install

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instalar Maven:

1. 1.-Descarga los binarios en zip.
2. 2.- Coloca el zip en un directorio deseado, por ejemplo en raiz  "C:\" , quedando la ruta completa: C:\apache-maven-3.2.2.zip
3. 3.- Descomprimir zip con winrar o 7zip por ejemplo.
4. 4.- A descomprimir los binarios, se crearà una carpeta C:\apache-maven-3.2.2, dentro de ese directorio se encuentran los
   binarios de maven.

Una vez colocado y descomprimido maven, crea las variables de entorno.

Pre-requisitos:
Variables de entorno java

```
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1. 7.0_17.
```

Variables para maven:

> M2= %M2_HOME%\bin
>
> M2_HOME= C:\apache-maven-3.2.2
>
> Path ...; C:\apache-maven-3.2.2\bin; ...

Mi sugerencia es reiniciar el pc al termino de  crear las variables de entorno.

Al reiniciar, abrir una consola CMD y teclear lo siguiente:

> mvn -version

Si todo quedo Ok, verà un mensaje :

> C:\Users\xxx>mvn -version Apache Maven 3.2.2
>   (45f7c06d68e745d05611f7fd14efb6594181933e; 2014-06-17T08:51:42-05:00)
>   Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.2.2 Java version: 1.6.0_35, vendor: Sun
>   Microsystems Inc. Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\jre
>   Default locale: es_MX, platform encoding: Cp1252 OS name: "windows 7",
>   version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows" C:\Users\xxx>

Està salida es con la versión: apache-maven-3.2.2

Comment: debo poner tal cual esta M2= %M2_HOME%\bin o solamente 
  %M2_HOME%\bin ?

Comment: Crea una nueva variable  "M2" y como valor le asignas " %M2_HOME%\bin", Ojo, sin comillas, de està forma, M2 apunta al valor de M2_HOME\bin

Comment: estaba confundiendo con crear una variable y variables de entorno

Comment: reinicie la maquina, ahora sale este error **Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher**

Comment: Hola, eche un vistazo del error y al parecer un bug.
1) Remove the M2_HOME variable from the path.

2) Add M3_HOME variable with the path to your maven 3 installation.

Comment: Agrego como tengo mis variables de ambiente:
Desde CMD:

Users\xxx>echo %M2%
apache-maven-3.2.2\bin

Users\xxx>echo %M2_HOME%
apache-maven-3.2.2

Users\xxx>echo %Path%
....;C:\apache-maven-3.2.2\bin

Comment: mis variables de entorno path:   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131;M3_HOME= C:\apache-maven-3.5.0;M2= %M3_HOME%\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.5.0\apache-maven\src\bin

Comment: Podrias abrir el cmd y con el comando echo, mostrar la salida de las variables M3_HOME, M2_HOME y M2 por fa, en  comentario anterior veras el comando a ejecutar

Comment: edite mi pregunta respondiendo a tu peticion revisalo porfavor.

Comment: desde cmd -version la respuesta es: Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T15:39:06-04:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Pr...

Answer (score 1):

### **INSTALÉ MAVEN EN WINDOWS 10**

Después de la Instalación me salía el mensaje: "**Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher**"

Sólo seguí las instrucciones de la página: **https://maven.apache.org/install.html** 
No requerí **"M2", "M2_HOME", "M3", "M3_HOME"** o algún otro.

1.- Descargué el **Binary zip archive** de la página: **https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#Installation** lo descomprimí en
**C:\apache-maven-3.6.1**

2.- Verifiqué mi "**JAVA_HOME**" (*Variables de entorno - Variables de usuario para...*) que tuviera la ruta de mi JDK  "**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171**"

3.- Verifiqué (agregué) mi "Path" "**C:\apache-maven-3.6.1**" tal como está escrito (*no le puse diagonal al final*).

4.- Verifiqué la versión de MAVEN con "**mvn -v**" y me arrojó la información correcta.

Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-04T13:00:29-06:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin..
Java version: 1.8.0_171, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre
Default locale: es_MX, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

y Listo!

Answer (score 0):

Hay un "espacio" que debes quitar, cambia esto `%JAVA_HOME%\bin; %M2%` por esto `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2%`

Comment: Hola. En primer lugar ¡Gracias por responder! Tu respuesta ha sido incluida en la lista de posibles respuesta de baja calidad debido a que es muy corta. En mi opinión, debieras explicar con más detalle por qué esto es un problema y/o cómo tu sugerencia resuelve el problema. No está de más decir que la sustitución debe hacerse en la variable `Path` (es lo que yo supongo). Te sugiero leer [answer] para mejorar la calidad de tus aportes y de nuevo gracias. Un saludo!